# Is it possible to perform Numpy.where() with a condition that is dependent on the previous index value?

Tags: python, numpy, signals

Essentially, as the question asks, I have a specific goal of speeding up a Numpy operation for real time signal processing by removing a for loop in which I need to find the time of a trigger point from a continuous input signal. Below is the for loop that currently works that I would like to replace:

```
trigger_times = np.empty()
for counter, sample in enumerate(data[0:-self.number_of_samples_per_pulse]):
     if sample[0] > SignalProcessor.activation_threshold and counter > 1:
         if np.mean(data[counter-1:counter][0]) < 0:
             trigger_times = np.append(trigger_times, counter*(1/self.sample_rate))
```

So far I have worked out I need to use Numpy.where(), but I have become a little confused beyond that as I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I need to do with this function. Is it possible to add conditional statements based on the previous value of a point in an array when doing np.where()? If not is there an alternative more optimised way of doing this? For the amount of data being operated on, this take a lot of time to process is all. Thanks.

Comment: First of all in your loop, you shouldn't be using `np.append`.  Use list append, it's faster, and easier to use right.

Comment: `data[counter-1:counter]` will only give you one element, .i.e, `data[counter-1]`. Also, did you maybe mean to do `data[counter-1:counter,0]` instead of `data[counter-1:counter][0]`?